# How arrays with an empty size works in c++?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm reading some materials about C++ and I just saw that array can be declared without a size (ex. int arr[], char x[][10]) and I'm wondering how/when it's actually used. Could someone explain both examples, please?

A more explicit example:

```
void foo(char[][10]);
```

Does that mean that any array like a[n][10], a[m][10] can be passed to the above function?

Comment: do you mean something like `int arr[] = {1,2,3};` ?

Comment: I know that the syntax is valid but how is it used?

Comment: "_I'm reading some materials about C++_": The material (if it is supposed to be teaching material) should explain it. In either case, please provide a more concrete example of the kind of code you saw. There are multiple contexts in which you might see such types and each will probably have a somewhat different answer. But I am sure that there are duplicates around for each of these individual situations. The currently linked duplicate considers variable declarations of such types without initializers, which is not the common case.

Comment: foo got issue that it doesn't "know size" of array.  It's as if you was passing a pointer to int[10], only a sugared syntax.

Comment: In a parameter list, `char[][10]` is equivalent to `char (*) [10]`; a pointer to an array of ten `char`s. That is, it's not an array but a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does that mean that any array like a[n][10], a[m][10] can be passed to the above function?*

Yes. The function signature `void foo(char[][10]);` is allowed as long as you pass a compatible argument, *i.e.* a char array with 2 dimensions in which the second has size `10`.

In fact, technically, the argument will decay to a pointer, so it's the same as having `void foo(char (*)[10]);`, a pointer to array of ten, in this case chars. An argument of type `char[]` will also decay, this time to a pointer to char (`char*`).

---

Furthermore omitting the first dimension of an array is permitted on declaration as long as you initialize it. The fist dimension of the array will be deduced by the compiler based on the initialization content, *i.e.*:

```
int arr[]{1,2};
```

will have size 2 (`arr[2]`) whereas

```
int arr[][2]{{1,2},{2,4}};
```

will become `arr[2][2]` based on the aggregate initialization.

Comment: I will add the full example from the article.

Comment: What a nice feature. So my guesses were valid?

Comment: @Ion yes they were.